# My for Loop only outputs the last result, can I change this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

So I'm trying to understand for loops a bit more but im wondering if there's a way to return each iteration of the loop rather than just the end result?

I know I could just list the items separately but I'd like to figure out a way where I can do it more efficiently and in case there were a large number of objects in an array.

```
function average(array) {

for (i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  return array[i]['number']/array.length
}

}

const array = [
  { user: 'a', number: 20 },
  { user: 'b', number: 21 },
  { user: 'c', number: 22 }
];
```

Comment: Your code should return the first value, not the last one

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want a list of numbers returned? What do you expect to happen if you ___return___ a value in a loop? That `return` statement immediately breaks out of the loop.

Comment: `for` loop doesn't have a return value, it just executes its body and after that the execution is continued from the next statement after the loop. `return` __returns from the function__, and your loop will never iterate through all the array members.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return from a normal function which will immediately break out of the loop when you issue the `return`; unless you use a generator function, denoted by the `function` keyword followed by an asterisk i.e. `function*` syntax.

This is as per your requirement that you don't want the items to be listed:

> I know I could just list the items separately but I'd like to figure
>   out a way where I can do it more efficiently

So in case of a generator function the `yield value` actually returns a `value` and pauses the execution of the running function and does not break out of the loop:

```js
const array = [
  { user: 'a', number: 20 },
  { user: 'b', number: 21 },
  { user: 'c', number: 22 }
];

function* average(array) {

  for (i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    yield array[i].number / array.length
  }

}

const avgGen = average(array);
// "..." spread operator gets all values from the iterable avgGen
console.log(...avgGen);
```

You can also use a `for-of` loop to iterate over the values one-by-one as the generator function call returns a `iterable` object:

```js
const array = [
  { user: 'a', number: 20 },
  { user: 'b', number: 21 },
  { user: 'c', number: 22 }
];

function* average(array) {

  for (i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    yield array[i].number / array.length
  }

}

let avgValue = average(array);
for(val of avgValue){
  console.log(val);
}
```

In the case of a normal function when you issue a return the loop is aborted and the immediate value is returned to the caller:

```js
const array = [
  { user: 'a', number: 20 },
  { user: 'b', number: 21 },
  { user: 'c', number: 22 }
];

function average(array) { //no asterisk

  for (i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    //loop is terminated with the first calculation or the first value
    return array[i].number / array.length 
  }

}

const avgGen = average(array); //one value is expected
console.log(avgGen);
```

The generator function on the other hand will temporarily **pause** the loop execution in the `yield` statement and yield/return an object like `{value: value, done: boolean}`. Note that when you execute the generator function it does not execute the code right away, it returns an `iterable` i.e. an object having a `next()` method and which can be iterated over.

When you call the `next()` on the returned `iterable` you get the first value. The iterable keeps on returning values to you till the loop has been exhausted.

```js
function* gen(){ //Note the asterisk
   yield 1; //pauses after each next() call
   yield 2;
   yield 3;
   return "completed";
}

const iterable = gen();// returns a iterable
const one = iterable.next();// get the first value {value: value, done: boolean}
console.log(one.value);
const two = iterable.next(); //loop resumed till yield 3
console.log(two.value);
const three = iterable.next();
console.log(three.value); //all values yielded
const final = iterable.next();
console.log(final.value); // value of the return statement
console.log(final.done); //done is true
```

Comment: While this may work, I'm not sure this helps the OP.  The OP doesn't understand loops (by his own admission), so I'm not sure introducing a concept like generator functions and a `yield`, will help.

Comment: @Cerbrus I will add some explanation shortly!

Comment: This is rather helpful and enlightening in terms of understanding certain aspects of the language. thanks for the help Ill be making sure I deconstruct what Ive learned to understand certain aspects a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

To return each value, you can use an additional **`results`** array that you fill using **[`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)** as you go:

```js
function average(array) {
  var results = [];
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    results.push(array[i]['number'] / array.length);
  }
  return results;
}

const array = [
  { user: 'a', number: 20 },
  { user: 'b', number: 21 },
  { user: 'c', number: 22 }
];

console.log(average(array));
```

Or more advanced: you can call **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)**, which will process all items and return a derived value for each of them:

```js
function average(array) {
  return array.map(item => item.number / array.length);
}

const array = [
  { user: 'a', number: 20 },
  { user: 'b', number: 21 },
  { user: 'c', number: 22 }
];

console.log(average(array));
```

Comment: I suspect something simple like a `map` is what the OP is looking for, although really, this question should be closed as "unclear"...

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward way, as far as I understand it, would be using JavaScript's `reduce`:

```
const average = array.reduce((sum, obj) => { return sum + obj.number;}, 0 ) / array.length;
```

If you don't want to use `reduce` and a bit easier to read:

```
let sum = 0;
array.forEach(obj => { sum += obj.number });
const average = sum / array.length;
```